# Java code to determine number of days elapsed does not return correct answer

Tags: java, date, datetime

The problem with this code is that it does calculate the days alive only for some birth dates. I tried using different birth dates and testing it with an online calculator and it seems not all are correct. I think the problem is because of Leapyears, more and less than 30 days in a month.

```
public class DaysAlive {

public static void main (String [] args){

    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

    int TodayYear, TodayMonth, TodayDay;
    int YearBorn, MonthBorn, DayBorn;
    int DaysAlive;

    System.out.println("Enter today's date");
    System.out.print ("Year: ");
    TodayYear = userInput.nextInt ();
    System.out.print ("Month: ");
    TodayMonth = userInput.nextInt ();
    System.out.print ("Day: ");
    TodayDay = userInput.nextInt ();

    System.out.println("Enter date of birth");
    System.out.print ("Year: ");
    YearBorn = userInput.nextInt ();
    System.out.print ("Month: ");
    MonthBorn = userInput.nextInt ();
    System.out.print ("Day: ");
    DayBorn = userInput.nextInt ();

    //I think this line is the problem 
    DaysAlive = (TodayYear - YearBorn) *365 + (TodayMonth - MonthBorn) *30 +(TodayDay - DayBorn);

    System.out.println("DaysAlive: " + DaysAlive);



      }
}
```

Comment: To take care of leap year and 30,31 days, take millisecond difference and then divide it by number of millis per day, stackoverflow.com/questions/5301226 Use this as reference create instance of Calendar or Date and then use the millisecond and use it in your calculation

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculating the Difference Between Two Java Date Instances](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555262/calculating-the-difference-between-two-java-date-instances)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you want, you should be able to use something like this -

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter today's date");
    System.out.print("Year: ");
    int todayYear = userInput.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Month: ");
    int todayMonth = userInput.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Day: ");
    int todayDay = userInput.nextInt();

    // Java has January as month 0. Let's not require that the user know.
    Calendar today = new GregorianCalendar(todayYear, todayMonth - 1,
            todayDay);

    System.out.println("Enter date of birth");
    System.out.print("Year: ");
    int yearBorn = userInput.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Month: ");
    int monthBorn = userInput.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Day: ");
    int dayBorn = userInput.nextInt();
    Calendar born = new GregorianCalendar(yearBorn, monthBorn - 1, dayBorn);

    double diff = today.getTimeInMillis() - born.getTimeInMillis();
    diff = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000); // hours in a day, minutes in a hour,
                                    // seconds in a minute, millis in a
                                    // second.
    System.out.println(Math.round(diff));
}
```

With output

```
Enter today's date
Year: 2014
Month: 03
Day: 14
Enter date of birth
Year: 2014
Month: 03
Day: 13
1
```

Answer (score 3):

How about using Calendar? It will do all of that for you... or joda time library

check it out here:
[Getting the number of days between two dates in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15556564/getting-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

You are right, the problem is that not all months have 30 days in them. A simple solution would to be use if statements and make another integer variable called something like monthMultiplier. As other people pointed out you can also use the Calendar

```
    if(TodayMonth == 9 || TodayMonth == 11 || TodayMonth == 4 || TodayMonth == 6) {
          monthMultiplier = 30;//30 days in these months

    } 

    if(TodayMonth == 2){
       monthMultiplier = 28;//WELL 28.25 accounting for leap years
    }

    else {
         monthMultiplier = 31;
}

    DaysAlive = (TodayYear - YearBorn) *365 + (TodayMonth - MonthBorn) * monthMultiplier +(TodayDay - DayBorn);
```

Answer (score 1):

## Joda-Time

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time) library makes easy work of this problem. Just one line of code, basically. Joda-Time handles time zones, leap days, and other issues.

Hand-coding such date-time work is risky, error-prone, and frankly silly given the excellent libraries available (Joda-Time and the new java.time package in Java 8).

### Example Code

Here’s some example code in Joda-Time 2.3.

```java
DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Paris" );

DateTime start = new DateTime(2008, 4, 26, 0, 0, 0, timeZone);
DateTime stop = new DateTime(2008, 5, 26, 0, 0, 0, timeZone);

int daysBetween = Days.daysBetween( start, stop ).getDays();
```

Dump to console…

```java
System.out.println( "start: " + start );
System.out.println( "stop: " + stop );
System.out.println( "daysBetween: " + daysBetween );
```

When executed…

```
start: 2008-04-26T00:00:00.000+02:00
stop: 2008-05-26T00:00:00.000+02:00
daysBetween: 30
```